# A question about cin in C++

Tags: c++, cin

When I declare `int weight` and then input a double value `165.1` a 2nd `cin >> height;` doesn't work and there is no any error message. Can you tell me why?

VS2010 Console Application used.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double lbs_to_kg = 2.2046, inches_to_meter = 39.370;

int main()
{
    int weight, height;
    double kilograms, meters;

    cout << "\nEnter weight in pounds: ";
    cin >> weight;
    kilograms = weight / lbs_to_kg;
    cout << "\nEnter height in inches: ";
    cin >> height;
    meters = height / inches_to_meter;
    cout << "\nYour BMI is approximately "
        << "\nbody fat ratio is "
        << kilograms / (meters * meters)
        << ". Under 25 is good."
        << endl;

}

output:

Enter weight in pounds: 165.1

Enter height in inches:
Your BMI is approximately
body fat ratio is 1.57219e-013. Under 25 is good.
```

Comment: Hmm.. that'd be an interesting body fat ratio.

Comment: @Billy: It's the Floating Point Diet. You spend so much time trying to understand the effects of floating point operations in your program, you forget to eat for a month.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you try to have `cin` extract data into a variable that can't hold it, the data is left in the input stream and `cin` is flagged as having failed. You need to check if it's failed with `!cin`, and use `cin.clear()` to clear the fail flag so you can read again (future extract operations will automatically fail until the flag is cleared). You can either extract the data into a different variable that's capable of holding it, or use `cin.ignore()` to discard it